# How do I call a sub from a form into my module?

Tags: vba, function, ms-access

I'm trying to run an autoexec macro in access.  I have a form called "Form_email".  within that is Public Sub Command0_click().

form_email

```
Public Sub Command0_click()
'stuff'
End Sub
```

Module

```
Public Function DoSomething()
docmd.openform'email'
Command0_click
End Function
```

Create a macro Autoexec with RunCode DoSomething
Open file and emails are sent automatically.
I get a compile error: Sub or Function not defined

Comment: `Command0_Click` belongs to *an instance* of the form object. You need to get ahold of a reference to the instance, and invoke the public member from there.

Comment: That said, making event handlers `Public` is a terrible practice. Consider keeping the handlers private and moving the `stuff` code into its own public procedure that both the handler and the form can call.

Comment: Mathieu, thank you very much for that.  I am very new to this, could you please be a little more descriptive?  I was looking through the references tab and could not find my form at all.  They are all in the same database.  Should I just put the    stuff directly into the DoSomething function?

Comment: You're using `DoCmd` to open the form. I'm not very familiar with Access forms and this global-default-instance paradigm, but I'll take a stab in the dark and say you could try accessing the global `Forms` collection, e.g. `Forms("email").Command0_Click`

Comment: Alternatively, replace `DoCmd.OpenForm` with `Dim theForm As Form_email`, then `Set theForm = New Form_email` and then you can make member calls against `theForm`, e.g. `theForm.Command0_Click`

Comment: that didn't completely work, but it did lead me to the solution.  Thank you!!!  Solution was just form_email.command0_click